# Cannot convert expression of type 'float64' to type 'int64'

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

    //float to int
    fmt.Println(int64(1.9))

}
```

I got syntax error "Cannot convert expression of type 'float64' to type 'int64'", how to rectify it?

Comment: Which version of Go are you using? The build error is `constant 1.9 truncated to integer`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Marc The version "go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64"

Comment: @kostix What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, the behaviour you're facing is [documented](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) as «The values of typed constants must always be accurately representable by values of the constant type. The following constant expressions are illegal: <…> int(3.14)    // 3.14 cannot be represented as an int». May be use `fmt.Println(math.Trunc(1.9))`?

Comment: Yes `const` can be confusing as [seen here](https://play.golang.org/p/hyEI9j82ukY). Large constants as well: this will [compile & run](https://play.golang.org/p/k3RTzQ8EMzX) - but this will [overflow at runtime](https://play.golang.org/p/Chrmpyeyorf) - but [this compiles/runs just fine](https://play.golang.org/p/wJCSXu-EZGV)

Comment: I think I have a slightly alternative explanation for your confusion: you could quite logically think that `1.9` is a constant expression and `int64` is a type cast (Go does not have type casts but let's not digress). Instead, the whole expression `int64(1.9)` would create a _typed_ constant from an _untyped_ constant `1.9`, so it's not really a type conversion as would occur in a "plain" expression—as opposed to a constant expression.

Comment: …and constants in Go live in a universe quite different to those values do—because values must be kept in variables, and those have must have "real-world" sizes (since Go is quite a low-level language). Constants, on the other hand, have quite different requirement for their precision and the evaluation rules of their expressions.

Answer (score 11):

Type [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) have special rules for constants:

> A constant value x can be converted to type T if x is representable by
> a value of T.

And even gives the following example:

```
int(1.2)                 // illegal: 1.2 cannot be represented as an int
```

---

If you really insist on truncating your float into an int, use a variable as an intermediary turning it into a non-constant conversion. Go will happily do the conversion and drop the fractional part, as mentioned further down in the spec:

> When converting a floating-point number to an integer, the fraction is
> discarded (truncation towards zero).

So you can use the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    //float to int
    f := 1.9
    fmt.Println(int64(f))
}
```

Which outputs `1` as expected.

---

Or use one of the functions in the [math](https://golang.org/pkg/math/) package if you want finer control over rounding vs truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Jut use the [math](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Floor) package:

```
int64(math.Floor(1.9))
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v7eLp5hxu5_1)